# Rest API Send Headers which are needed to be then returned by API

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, http-headers

Is it possible to send Request-headers to SharePoint Rest API which will be then present with the same value in the response?

Here is an example what I want to do:

```
getUserId: function (loginName, callback) {

    /// according to the environment.
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(decodeURIComponent(AppCoreFunctions.getAppRelativeUrls().appweburl));
    var url = AppCoreFunctions.getAppRelativeUrls().appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='" + SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.urlKeyValueEncode(loginName) + "'&@target='" + AppCoreFunctions.getAppRelativeUrls().hostweburl + "'";
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "__xyz": "123" //<-- I want to be able to read this data from response
        },
        success: function (data, loginName) {
            var JSONData = JSON.parse(data["body"]);
            callback(JSONData);
        },
        error: function (sender, args) {
            console.log(sender);
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is impossible, unless you can change how the receiving server responds, so in SharePoints case only Microsoft can make that change

Use either

- Scope binding
- Cookies
- Local Storage